# HTML/JavaScript tabs graceful degrade

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

Trying to find a good solution for tabbed based navigation on a website that I'm building. Currently I'm using jquery ui tabs but don't like the default behavior when it degrades with JavaScript turned off. Was wondering what some good solutions for this might be. I'm more than open to any solution and I'm comfortable with the relavant technologies. Website is being built in c# mvc3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *simplest* solution would be to simply link to separate files, e.g. :

```
<ul>
     <li href="index.html">Home</li>
     <li href="about.html">About</li>
     ...
</ul>
```

And [style](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/index.htm) them to look like tabs.

Alternatively, you could design something simple, and then add a stylesheet through Javascript for users that have it.

Comment: I'll consider that.  I like the way that jquery tabs functions however and would prefer a single paged solution (if there's a good one out there).